# How do "special" epoll flags correspond to kqueue ones?

Tags: nonblocking, epoll, kqueue, epollet, kevent

I'm struggling to draw a parallel between epoll and kqueue flags, specifically `EPOLLONESHOT EPOLLET EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` and EV_CLEAR/EV_DISPATCH/EV_ONESHOT. I'm investigating the kqueue for the first time; I only had an experience with epoll.

**EV_DISPATCH**

It feels like the mix of EPOLLEXCLUSIVE and EPOLLONESHOT flags; from the kqueue documentation:

```
EV_DISPATCH  Disable the event source immediately after delivery of an
             event.  See EV_DISABLE above.
EV_DISABLE   Disable the event so kevent()  will not return it.  The fil-
             ter itself is  not disabled.
```

Do I understand the documentation correctly that the event is signalled and then immediately discarded, if there was at least one kqueue instance which polled for this event? That is, if we poll a socket for EVFILT_READ on two kqueues, only one will receive it, and then, until the same event is set with EVFILT_ENABLE, there won't be any further events at all, even if new data comes to socket?

**EV_CLEAR**

Looks like it is close to EPOLLET; from the kqueue documentation:

```
EV_CLEAR      After the event is retrieved by the user, its state is
              reset.  This is useful for filters which report state tran-
              sitions instead of the current state.  Note that some fil-
              ters may automatically set this flag internally.
```

So, for example, given the same socket with EVFILT_READ, all kqueues, which poll it simultaneously, will wake up with EVFILT_READ. If, however, not all data is read (i.e. until EAGAIN), no further events are reported. If and only if all the data was read **and** a new data arrives, a new EVFILT_READ event would be triggered. Is it correct?

**EV_ONESHOT**

Looks like it maps to EPOLLONESHOT; from the kqueue documentation:

```
EV_ONESHOT   Causes the event to return only the first occurrence of the
             filter being triggered.  After the user retrieves the  event
             from the kqueue, it is deleted.
```

**Questions**

So, the questions:

1. Is my understanding correct? Did I understand these special flags right, compared to epoll? The documentation seems to be a bit tricky to me; perhaps the problem is that I've only used epoll before and didn't yet played with kqueue.
2. Could you please provide good sources or examples to see kqueue techniques? It would be nice if it would be not that complex like Boost.Asio; it would be also nice these sources would be written in C.
3. Can these flags be combined together? For example, EPOLLONESHOT cannot be combined with EPOLLEXCLUSIVE, but EV_DISPATCH seems to be exactly something in the middle between these flags.

Thank you for your help!

**References**

[kqueue(2): FreeBSD System Calls Manual](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2)

[epoll(7): Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html)

[epoll_ctl(7): Linux Programmer's Manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html)

Answer (score 2):

1. `EV_CLEAR` is not equal to `EPOLLET`, e.g. some listen socket has 5 pending connections, and you don't consume all of them(`accept` until `EAGAIN`), then with `EV_CLEAR`, you won't get `EVFILT_READ` event from `kevent` until the 6th connection appears.
2. `EPOLLEXCLUSIVE` is used for CPU binding, it isn't related to `EV_DISPATCH`.
3. `EV_ONESHOT` means delete `knote` after the specific event is triggered, while `EV_DISPATCH` only disable it.
4. If one socket fd is registered to several kqueues, then the event is broadcasted while the event is triggered.
5. `EV_ONESHOT` is almost equal to `EPOLLONESHOT`, it is useful in the case that different threads need to call `kevent` with same kqueue fd.

Comment: EPOLLEXCLUSIVE is not for CPU binding, flag says that if on same resource (pipe/queue/socket/etc..) several processes or threads waits for event, then wake up only one process/thread instead of all waking up all of them. Thus to avoid thundering herd issue, where all processes are waken up for single event (where event further is processed by one process, but other processes will get EAGAIN or similar error). Thus EPOLLEXCLUSIVE allows to eliminate CPU resource wasting.